# Facing Mixed DML operation for apex class

Tags: apex, class, exception, mixed-dml

I have written a scheduler for deactivating salesforce users who doesn't logged in for last 90 days. The code is working as expected if I remove exception logging into a salesforce object at line #14. When I put this facing Mixed DML operation (Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you...)

Please help me to resolve this exception.

```
public class DeactivateInactiveUsers implements Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        try{
            List<string> toAddress = new List<string>();
            User[] selectedUsers = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE AND Id NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM LoginHistory WHERE LoginTime = LAST_N_DAYS:90)];
            for(User record: selectedUsers) {
                record.IsActive = false;
                toAddress.add(record.email);
            }
            Database.update(selectedUsers, false);
        }
        catch(System.Exception e) {
            String strException = 'Exception Type: ' + e.getTypeName() + '-Message: ' + e.getMessage() + '-Cause: ' + e.getCause() + '-Line Number: ' + e.getLineNumber() + '-Stack Trace: ' + e.getStackTraceString();
            ErrorloggingClass.logErrors(strException, 'DeactivateUser');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By allowing partial updates (`Database.update(records, false)`), you're allowing a partial update; if an exception is later thrown, you've already modified some user records, and so you'd get this exception. Your best option would be to change your `ErrorloggingClass` to use Platform events to deliver the exception data asynchronously to a [Platform Event Trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_apex.htm) and log the data.